# Handling "with open()" errors?

Tags: python

So I got this code here:

```
with open(os.path.join(Path, 'ki/lol/kappa/file.txt'), 'r') as masterfile:
```

How can I add a function that tells the user that the file "file.txt" was not found in this directory? I get an error which is called `IOError [Errno 2] No such file in this directory` after starting my program. How can I show a message like "No file found here" instead of having this error appearing?

Comment: By Exception handling

Comment: Read about [handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Your question is fair, but it is receiving downvotes, because it doesn't meet the "how to ask a question" criteria: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You use a `try` statement. This is called Exception Handling. See [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception.

```
try:
    with open(os.path.join(Path, 'ki/lol/kappa/file.txt'), 'r') as masterfile:
        print "yay"
except IOError:
     print "Oops, couldn't open the file"
```